# getting data through association in Rails PG Sequel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, sequel

I have one table `cameras` and what options am available with is `current_user.id`. In cameras table, every camera have an `owner_id` which is actually the user's id who added the camera. Cameras for the current user can be get like this

```
user_cameras = Camera.where(owner_id: current_user.id).order(:id).all
```

But I have an other table `camera_shares` in which there is an `camera_id` and a `user_id` (with whom the camera has been shared), What i am doing is, Getting all those shares first where the `user_id` is `current_user.id` and then get all those `camera_id`'s and through them I get cameras as

```
camera_shares = CameraShare.where(user_id: current_user.id).all

camera_share_ids = []
camera_shares.each do |share|
  camera_share_ids[camera_share_ids.count] = share.user_id
end

@shared_cameras = Camera.where(id: camera_share_ids).order(:id).all
```

What I am looking is a way to make some join in the very first query where am getting user cameras, So that in one query I can get all the user owned cameras and as well as those which have been shared with him, As In camera_shares, I have the refernce of `user_id` and also camera_id.

I that possible to solve all this mess in one single query?

UPDATE: Camera.rb details

```
class Camera < Sequel::Model
  include Hashie::Extensions::Mash
  many_to_one :vendor_model, class: 'VendorModel', key: :model_id
  one_to_many :endpoints, class: 'CameraEndpoint'
  many_to_one :owner, class: 'User', key: :owner_id
  one_to_many :shares, class: 'CameraShare'
  one_to_many :webhooks, class: 'Webhook'
  one_to_one :cloud_recording
  one_to_one :motion_detection
```

CameraShares details

```
class CameraShare < Sequel::Model
    # Share kind constants.
    PRIVATE                   = 'private'.freeze
    PUBLIC                    = 'public'.freeze
    ALL_KINDS                 = [PRIVATE, PUBLIC]
    # Class relationships.
    many_to_one :camera
    many_to_one :user
    many_to_one :sharer, class: 'User', key: :sharer_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
user_cameras = Camera.includes(:owner, :users).where(owner_id: current_user.id).order(:id).all
```

Assuming you have something like following in `camera.rb`

```
has_one :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
has_many :cameras_shares
has_many :users, through: cameras_shares
```

EDITED

```
user_cameras = Camera.includes(:owner, :shares).where(owner_id: current_user.id).order(:id).all
```

Comment: are you serious ? I dont even see any reference of camera_shares in this?

Comment: Can you please share associations mentioned in `camera.rb`

Comment: I have added both Models and they are Sequel models.

Comment: Check my edited answer `user_cameras.first.owner` will give you object of the `owner`. `user_cameras.first.shares` will give you array of all the users with which camera was shared

Comment: YOu are not understand me Salil sorry

Comment: See both models above may question is = Cameras OK fine, But shares have a refernce user_ids, those user_ids have a camera_id and I want those cameras with those camera ids